# Drupal Views.. how to combine duplicate values and then display nodes that have that value?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I have a site where students can post their own content on it. Whenever they create content they are asked to type in their School Name. Since there will be multiple students from the same school I want to combine all of the duplicate values for the School Name field. I also want to link each School Name so it displays content from only the selected School. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really should consider using the school_name variable for a taxonomy vocabulary (http://drupal.org/node/23405), this way, the field wont be a duplicate, because it references the same term in the vocabulary.

then, when creating the content-type (or user) fields, use the 'relation to taxonomy' field option.

since it seems like you do not know all possible schools, use the tag widget.

in any case, you should think about deduplication, since this builtin method is not considering misspellings or different spellings of the same school name. (although the tag field has a autocomplete function).

a better approach is to present the user with all possible schools, however, that means you need to know all possible schools..

[EDIT] this, of course, is suggesting you are using drupal7 (or later). if not, use cck instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags, it seems the situation is Drupal-6.

I think for you to get really good advice, we would need more information about the scope of the project and how many schools would be covered. If you are talking about a worldwide or US-wide scope, there are many schools with the same name, so you might need a school name / City combination (or something) to have a unique identifier for a school. I would suggest you have some way of selecting from a preset list, whether the project covers just a small school district, or there are thousands of schools, that way you won't have issues with duplicate "schools" created during the content creation process.

Since taxonomy terms are not fieldable entities in Drupal 6, you might want to consider creating a separate content type for schools (which would allow you to include location information, etc) and which would be represented as a node reference when students enter content that identifies a school. In Drupal 7, a vocabulary should work for the "school", since you can add fields, but there might be modules that you'd want to use which work better with nodes (a content type) than with fieldable entities (e.g. adding location data or other fields to a vocabulary).